# how to return multiple variable with jsonresult in mvc from controller to view?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, view, return-value, viewbag

in below code, i pass two parameters one is a list and second is viewbag message, but in view, side can't use viewbag.
So how to use it, please anyone help me
[image]

in **view**
[image]

where to i place viewbag message

Comment: How does controller action specified by `urlAction` looks like?

Comment: @OndraNetočný in above i specified  like `var urlAction = '@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")'; and this urlAction pass into url: urlAction;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand to your question, you should create new class that holds both your list and message (instead of passing that to ViewBag).

```
public class YourResponse
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<SomeContent> Content { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your action in controller, create a new instance of this class and fill in the values and pass this instance back to the client.

```
public ActionResult YourActionName()
{
    // do the stuff here to get message and list
    var response = new YourResponse
    {
        Message = message, //insert your message here
        Content = list //and list of data here
    }
    return Json(response);
}
```

And finally read and use the data from server within client code.

```
function OnSuccessed(data)
{
    var message = data.Message;
    var list = data.Content;
    // you can work with message and list here
}
```

Just note that this is raw example, I have not run the code.

Answer (score 2):

> create custom class

```
     private class LineData
     {
        public string y { get; set; }
        public string item1 { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public List<LineData> list { get; set; }
    }
```

> In controller side

[image]

> In view 
>   
>   [image]